# General parametric solution of Diophantine Equation--4th Powers

Tags: terminology, diophantine-equations, parametric

In the following link we can read (highlighted) about Diophantine equation $A^4 + B^4 = C^4 + D^4$ that it has no "general" parametric solution and yet in next sentence we can read that equation $x^4 + y^4 = u^4 + v^4$ has general (but incomplete) parametric solution.

[Diophantine Equation--4th Powers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation4thPowers.html#:%7E:text=no%20%22general%22%20solution%20is%20known&text=General%20(but%20incomplete)%20solutions%20are%20given%20by)

Can you explain what the author probably meant?
If I say general solution I would probably mean complete solution but the author uses "incomplete general solution". What is it?

What of the four following combinations has any sense and which?

- incomplete general parametric solution
- complete general parametric solution
- incomplete non-general parametric solution
- complete non-general parametric solution

PS: Some text should have been highlighted in the link but it does not seem to work. I do not know why.

PS2: There is a bug on your site... in the `Hyperlink` the character `~` is changed into `%7E` which spoils scrolling to chosen text and highlighting it.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.- A complete general parametric solution is for example given by the very known Pythagorean triples
$$x=s^2-t^2\\y=2st\\z=s^2-t^2$$ solving the equation $x^2+y^2=z^2$.

On the other hand the parameterization
$$x=m-5\\y=-m+14\\z=3m-30\\w=-3m+29$$ solves partially only the equation
$$n=x^3+y^3+z^3+w^3$$ of the representation of a rational integer as a sum of four cubes which is conjecturally analogue to  Lagrange's theorem for the squares. This is an example of incomplete general parametric solution because it represents only the integers of the form $18m+8$.

Comment: But why would it be called `general` solution of `sum of four cubes`? What would be non-general solution then?

Comment: I guess, **non more**, that "incomplete general parametric solution" refers to an infinite class of solutions, not only several solutions. A general solution for representation of a integer number as sum of four cubes would involve all the integers, all the solutions of $n=x^3+y^3+z^3+w^3$ for all $n$.